# Динамический фильтр SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Есть таблица в базе примерно такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне на вход приходит список тегов в таком формате:

```
[{"key": "key1", "value": "value1"}, {"key": "key2", "value": "value2"}]
```

И мне надо через sqlalchemy вернуть список имен, у которых есть нужные теги.
Здесь это ['name1', 'name3']

Вот я не совсем понимаю как написать фильтр для такого запроса:

```
query = conn.query(MyTable).filter(...)
```

Comment: а как же name2?

Comment: в том-то и сложность, что он мне не нужен в выдаче. Только те названия, у которых есть все теги из списка

Comment: вам нужно что-то такое, но как это реализовывать на алхимии, не подскажу - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a160c83/2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604967/sqlalchemy-build-query-filter-dynamically-from-dict

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215644/sqlalchemy-how-to-using-and-in-or-operation